# webmin cron not running per minute

Tags: amazon-ec2, cron, webmin

I'm using `Webmin` on my `AWS EC2 Instance`

I have created few cron tasks to run every minute.

setup for one cron job is like
[image]

in script mode

**/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root**

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.abHzd4/crontab installed on Wed Feb  7 06:53:10 2018)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
1 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/public_html && bin/cake generate_script auto_post
1 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/public_html && bin/cake generate_script timeline
1 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/public_html && bin/cake queue runworker
5 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/public_html && bin/cake social_upload upload
2 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/public_html && bin/cake delete_youtube_videos delete
```

**But it does not run every minute.**

Also, how to enable cron logging in Webmin?

Answer (score 1):

You have set it to run at the first minute of every hour. If you want it to run every minute, select "ALL" in the Minute column and all other columns as well (Hours, Days, Months, Weekdays).

*If you want to run it after every 5 minutes then you'll have to do multiple selections in the minutes' column by keeping the CTRL key pressed and with the help of the mouse, select 0, 5, 10, 15, 20,..., 50, 55* ~same goes for hours, days, months!

You can restart the CRON service by using the following command in Ubuntu:

```
# For checking the status
sudo service cron status

# For restarting the service
sudo service cron restart
```

For enabling the corn logging in Webmin / Virtualmin:

Go to: **Webmin > System > System Logs**

And click on the row **File /var/log/cron.log**

Then search for (CTRL+F) the text: **Logging active?** and select **Yes**

Now click on the Green **Save** button.

CRON Logging in Webmin is now active.

Now you can restart the corn service for the safe side.

You can view the log file in the **Webmin>System>System Logs** page by clicking on the **view** button that is appearing at the right-side corner of the **File /var/log/cron.log** row.

Answer (score 0):

It would take some time for your cron jobs to be updated.

Try running from console or theme command shell `(Alt+K)` the following command to restart crond and re-read the files:

```
systemctl status crond.service
```

Comment: But I can not do this all time as this is a background process.

Comment: You need to do it only once, after editing _cron_ jobs. However, we're going to fix this bug, so _crond_ would be automatically applied.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old question, but on the picture it seems you set it to run every first minute in every hour (not every minute)